# How to make a subsample from a dataset with equal labels, like the sklearn.digit dataset

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, dataset

For our demonstration, we’ll just use the ten digits dataset from sklearn. Pendigits dataset consists of 10 classes from digit 0 to digit 9.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
digits = load_digits()
print(digits.data.shape)
print(digits.target.shape)
```

Output looks like -

```
(1797, 64)
(1797,)
```

So each digit consists of some sample dataset. I would like to have a subsample of each class from the dataset. For example from digit 0 to digit 9, I need 50 subsamples of each class present in the dataset.

```
print(digits.data.shape)
print(digits.target.shape)
```

Result should be(50 subsample * 10 class = 500 subsample) -

```
(500,64)
(500)
```

Result should consist of subsample of each class available in the dataset.

Answer (score 2):

One option can be to use [`sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) and use `stratify` on labels *`(here : digits.target)`* to split data in a stratified fashion.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
import numpy as np

digits = load_digits()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(digits.data, digits.target,
                                                    stratify=digits.target, 
                                                    train_size=500)

# we can check labels that split equality like below
print(np.unique(y_train, return_counts=True))
# (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
# array([50, 51, 49, 51, 50, 51, 50, 50, 48, 50]))

print(X_train.shape)
# (500, 64)

print(y_train.shape)
# (500,)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

digits = load_digits()
X, _, y, _ = train_test_split(
    digits.data, digits.target,
    stratify=digits.target, train_size=500
)
X.shape, y.shape #((500, 64), (500,))
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality) queue because it lacks an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32302722)

Comment: The other answer is a good example of how to write answers on SO.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney yes it is. For this reason I up-voted that answer, although it was identical to my solution.